# How can I read the last 10 lines from a text file?

Tags: scanning

I have a logfile, snd I would like to search for keywords in it. But I only want to examine the last 10 lines, not the whole text. Could you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

On linux and mac or any *nix terminal emulator on windows (e.g. cygwin) you could do something like this:

```
tail -n 10 filename.txt | grep "pattern to search"
```

Comment: I’m using windows, so i can’t use this method for my problem.